# Weird input from a file using fscanf()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

My main objective here is to make use of `fscanf()` to take in each word from my file and store it into an array location. As it stands, I loop through the file setting each word to a location in `wordList[]`. I can print out the values as they are put into the array and each seems to be placed correctly. But after the loop, when I attempt to print only one of the values (simply checking that everything went as it should) I get a weird output. When printing the string contained in `wordList[5]`, it prints the first character of every word after location `[5]`, and prints the last word that was collected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readFile (FILE *fPtr, char *fileName) {
    FILE *newFilePtr;
    char wordList[1000];
    int i = 0;

    newFilePtr = fopen(strcat(fileName, ".out"), "w");          // Blank document created under same file name, but with ".out"

    while(fscanf(fPtr, "%s", &wordList[i]) == 1) {              // Read in strings from main file into wordList
        printf("%s\n", &wordList[i]);
        ++i;

        if (i > 10)                                             // KEEP OUTPUT SHORT FOR STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION
            break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", &wordList[5]);                     // PRINTS WILD VALUE AT POSITION 5
    fclose(newFilePtr);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int lineSize;
    char *fileName = argv[2];                                   // Store name of file for future operations
    FILE *fPtr;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "ERROR: Incorrect arguments. Please input a line size and a file.\n");
        return;
    }

    lineSize = atol(argv[1]);                                   // Convert string to it's integer equivalent

    if (lineSize < 25 || lineSize > 100) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "ERROR: Line size not within range.\n");
        return;
    }

    if (fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r")) {                          // If the file exists, open it for reading
        readFile(fPtr, fileName);
        puts("FILE OPENED SUCCESS");
        fclose(fPtr);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "ERROR: File could not be opened.\n");
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

And my current output (constrained to just the first 10 values to keep it short):

`Mason–Dixon
Line
(or
Mason
and
Dixon's
Line)
was
surveyed
between
1763
DLwsb1763              // Should print "Dixon's" (the string at location 5)
FILE OPENED SUCCESS`

The creation of the new file at `line 11` is for later use when the file is formatted. For now, i'm only concerned with properly scanning in the values from the original file.

Comment: Hmm... I have a suspicion about `strcat`ing into `argv[2]` being UB...

Comment: 1) `strcat(fileName, ".out")` : `fileName` does not have enough space to concatenate.

Comment: 2) `char wordList[1000];` --> `char wordList[11][WORD_LENGTH];`

Comment: The new file is created for when the original file is formatted, it is to be output into that new file. Is there a better way to create a new file under the same name, but only with the ".out" extension attached?

Comment: `char fileName[strlen(argv[2]) + sizeof(".out")];strcpy(fileName, argv[2]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Maybe you missed one more statement:
strcat(fileName, ".out");

Comment: @StevensonRJames It is in `readFile` and there is no need to change it.

Comment: Thank you for that. My initial problem still remains, the file could contain any amount of words, but for the sake of this problem we're assuming its under 1000. Each word needs to be in its own spot, with no spaces added. Also, the length of each word or the maximum length is not known.

Comment: Given `char wordList[1000];`, your code `while(fscanf(fPtr, "%s", &wordList[i]) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", &wordList[i]);
        ++i; … }` reads the first word over `wordList[0]` and following, the second over `wordlist[1]` and following (so only the first character of the first word is left undamaged), and so on.  You need to rethink how you're handling the words.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY My bets are on your 2). May I ask you to be nice and write a few more words than that (totally informative) telegram? Maybe even in the shape of an answer? OP might be flushed by the other (also insightful) comments.

Comment: A well presented question. Please do not provide a working solution, since another recently asked (and deleted) question was on the same homework theme. The salient points are about modifying/extending program arguments, and needing a 2-D `char` array for the dictionary. My choice would be a 1-D array of `char*` pointers, using `strdup` to create the dictionary from a generous input string.

Comment: Thank you for the insight Jonathan and Weather Vane. I've done some modification and came up with this `while (i < 1000 && fscanf(fPtr, "%s", wordList[i]) == 1) {       
       ++i;
   }`, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. I have created my wordList as an array of pointers, with a size of 1000. Through each iteration, wouldn't this essentially grab each string, and place it in the location of `wordList[i]`? Thank you again for the assistance.

Comment: Pointers in an array of pointers must point to something. You will need to allocate space for each string. Suggest reading about `strdup()` and following the advice of [@WeatherVane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192106/weird-input-from-a-file-using-fscanf#comment73460594_43192106). Note that `strdup()` is not a Standard Library function, but is POSIX. You may need to use a feature test macro to enable it by adding as the very first line of your source code: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`.

Comment: Perhaps the modified code could be a new question, since it is unclear where you moved to. You quite rightly refrained from editing the original question to be "dynamic to-fro-stuff" which does not work here. N.B. if you want to flag the attention of a commenter the method is, for example @JonathanLeffler (only one per comment).